# Convert okular-pdf with annotations to normal pdf

Tags: pdf, okular

I was asked to proofread a dissertation for somebody using only Windows. I use Debian 7 and opened the PDF with okular and commented it heavily.

Everytime I opened the document and then closed it again, the comments were available and it, only at the end, turned out that the comments are not saved to the pdf-File, but rather some obscure and weird external xml lying around somehwere.

My friend for whom I reviewed his work does only have Windows. It's quite confusing reading about this stuff online because it's claimed that okular now supports this, but I couldn't get the installation done

```
[  0%] Built target okularcore_automoc
[ 24%] Built target okularcore
[ 24%] Built target okularpart_automoc
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/okularpart.dir/part.cpp.o
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp: In constructor ‘Okular::Part::Part(QWidget*, QObject*, const QVariantList&, KComponentData)’:
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp:441:19: error: ‘class KMessageWidget’ has no member named ‘setIcon’
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp: At global scope:
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp:929:6: warning: unused parameter ‘column’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp: In member function ‘Okular::Document::OpenResult Okular::Part::doOpenFile(const Ptr&, const QString&, bool*)’:
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp:1230:66: warning: ‘QString KMimeType::parentMimeType() const’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/kmimetype.h:332) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool Okular::Part::openFile()’:
/home/zodiac/Dokumente/franzi/t3/okular/part.cpp:1400:25: error: ‘class KMessageWidget’ has no member named ‘setIcon’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/okularpart.dir/part.cpp.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/okularpart.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

Now, there has to be any way to convert those annotations quickly and without (!) retyping all of them to a format that a Windows-PDF-reader is able to read. I even tried KDE for Windows and exporting it to a document-archive, but on Windows it cannot read the file and crashes. Things like Okular2PDF.jar seem to work... kind of. They put really large comment-icons on the screen, all of which say "The quick brown fox...".

It's really annoying that such a basic feature is implemented in such a terrible and absolutely useless and unintuitive way. Is there any way to EASILY convert the file?

Comment: Late comment: the annotations are saved as `xml` file under `~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`. It have to be a similar directory for windows. It is possible to try to copy there the file...

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation (https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html):

> Since Okular 0.15 you can also save annotations directly into PDF
>   files. This feature is only available if Okular has been built with
>   version 0.20 or later of Poppler rendering library. **You can use File
>   → Save As... to save the copy of PDF file with annotations.**

I have tried it and worked fine, using Okular 0.23.2 for commenting, and Sumatra PDF 3.0 (on Windows 8.1) for viewing.